# nutch parse custom xml with tika using xpath

Tags: nutch, apache-tika

I am new to nutch.
nutch 1.7
I am looking at ways to parse custom xml files based on xpath and store the data.  I did see the xml_parser plugin but that's suspended since tika has taken over.
How do I configure tika embedded within nutch 1.7 to parse the url content based on xpath.  I have searched all nutch documentation/wiki but there's not much information there. 
tika tries to parse and extract the content which fails because of the custom format, but I want to store the xml with tags based on the xpath. Where should I put the xpath info in the nutch conf? Or do I have to override the tike parser?

Any hints on the right direction much appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can easily do this with tika but you may use these custom plugins to parse xml files based on xpath:

- https://github.com/BayanGroup/nutch-custom-search
- http://www.atlantbh.com/precise-data-extraction-with-apache-nutch/